# Javascript object that maps keys to value & allows iteration over keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create object in javascript that allows to fetch values using keys & also iterate over keys.  The primary requirement is fetching value by key but iteration is required to maintain sort order of entries by values(integer).

How do I go about creating such an object ?

Comment: check this post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-to-iterate-over-a-json-structure

Comment: @ManMohan Vyas: just iteration is ok, but how to retrieve value by key ?

Comment: @user01: Retrieve value by key is easy: the most general way is obj['keyname'], a less general way is obj.keyname

Comment: @nhahtdh: Thanks. Please also suggest a way to append entries to   `sampleJson={
"1":"john",
"2":"johny"
}` to add `"3":"johnyoo"`

Comment: @user01: You should get a good book on JS before even start coding. As for that sampleJson['3'] = "johnyoo". But the problem is, normal JS Object won't fulfill your second condition of "maintain sort order of entries by values(integer)" while allow fetching by key.

Comment: @user01 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503193/nested-json-how-to-add-push-new-items-to-an-object check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sampleJson={
"1":"john",
"2":"johny"
}
```

You can iterate using for in loop

```
for(key in sampleJson){
//ur code
}
```

Comment: how to retrieve value by key ? for eg, when querying with "1" as key it should give "john"

Comment: Do you read the question carefully? There is also the part: "maintain sort order of entries by values(integer)."

Comment: for(key in sampleJson){alert(sampleJson[key])}

Answer (score 1):

1. All objects in JavaScript are JSONeable! (is that really a word).
2. All objects in JavaScript are a collection of key value mappings.
3. A `for` `in` loop iterates over the keys of an object.

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question: "maintain sort order of entries by values(integer)."

Answer (score 0):

Native objects don't support exactly what you're looking for, but it's fairly straightforward to create a wrapper around native objects that provides extra functionality.

A possible approach:

```
function KeySortArr(obj) {
    this.obj = obj || {};
}

KeySortArr.prototype = {
    get: function(key) {
        return this.obj[key];
    },

    set: function(key, value) {
        this.obj[key] = value;
    },

    keys: function() {
        var keys = [];
        for(var i in this.obj) {
            if (this.obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
                keys.push(i);
        }
        return keys;
    },

    getKeysSortedByValue: function() {
        var obj = this.obj;
        return this.keys().sort(function(a, b) {
            return obj[a] > obj[b];
        });
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
var arr = new KeySortArr();
arr.set("test", 4);
arr.set("another", 2);
arr.set("ok", 60);
arr.set("last", 14);
```

The following then:

```
arr.getKeysSortedByValue();
```

Returns:

```
["another, "test", "last", "ok"]
```

In other words, the keys are sorted by their associated value. This might not be exactly what you were looking for, but it should be close.