# Javascript how to add new object to object in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i need to create array of objects like this one

```
var vegetables = "babana": {"store": store, "foo": foo}, "tomato": {"store": store, "foo": foo}, "orange": {"store": store, "foo": foo};
```

im getting all the data from a loop and my loop like this one:

```
for(var v in vegetablesData) {
    // this code dosent work with "=" its only adding the last entry from the array
   // the data of the 'store' and 'foo' are taken from somewhere other place from the code, i didnt wrote from where, because im thinking that is it irrelevant to my question
    test[vegetables[v]] = {"store": store, "foo": foo};
}
```

the output i need it should be in this format (using JSON.stringify(vegetables)):

```
{"vegetables": {"babana": {"store": store, "foo": foo}, {"tomato": {"store": store, "foo": foo}, "orange": {"store": store, "foo": foo}}
```

i tied to do it with

> .push

but its not working. I laso tried with += and still it dosent work. I'm noob, so i need your help. thanks!

Comment: i don't see any arrays.

Comment: your target "array of objects" is not an array of objects

Comment: .push is array not objects as you have found out. So you have to set it. For example, vegatbles['banana'] = ... or vegatables.banana =

Comment: where is `test` defined? where is `vegetablesData` defined etc etc etc ... without seeing what you are actually starting with, an answer is difficult. While often you get better responses if you show you've tried something, what you've tried shows you have no idea what the question is

Comment: it's not difficult at all @JaromandaX he's using the object as an array and it isn't an array it's an object. So he needs to learn how to work with objects, sure the solution is easily found

Comment: Your JSON is also malformed. Your vegetable objects need to be nested in `[]`

Comment: Your code should work unless either `test`, `vegerables` or `vegetablesData` are incorrectly defined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503193/nested-json-how-to-add-push-new-items-to-an-object

Comment: Make sure to spell "vegetable" consistently. You've spelled it three different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you're not working on an array.

The `for` syntax you're using if in fact iterating over the keys of an object. If you want to add an object to an object, simply use a key and a value like this.

```
obj[key] = value
```

In your example, you're setting the content of the `vegetable` for a key `v` as the key of the object `test.

```
for(var v in vegetablesData) {
    test[v] = {"store": store, "foo": foo};
}
```

It's not really clear what you have in test, but you might end up doing something like this:

```
 test['vegetables'] = {}
 for(var v in vegetablesData) {
     test['vegetables'][v] = {"store": store, "foo": foo};
 }
```

Comment: thank you this way is working great! :D but the problem was in my code as i was declaring the object every time like this test['vegetables'] = {} in the loop and thats why i was only getting the last entry. it took me 2 hours to find that out, lol :D

Answer (score -1):

[Nested JSON: How to add (push) new items to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503193/nested-json-how-to-add-push-new-items-to-an-object)

Example above does it like so :

```
library[title] = {"foregrounds" : foregrounds, "backgrounds" : backgrounds};
```

As said in the comments, you're treating the object like an array, it's not an array so `.push` wont work so you have to set it like above.

You're not using the correct element in the object either. So instead of :

```
for(var v in vegetablesData) {
    // this code dosent work with "=" its only adding the last entry from the array
   // the data of the 'store' and 'foo' are taken from somewhere other place from the code, i didnt wrote from where, because im thinking that is it irrelevant to my question
    test[vegerables[v]] = {"store": store, "foo": foo};
}
```

Use this :

```
for(var veg in vegetablesData) {
    // this code dosent work with "=" its only adding the last entry from the array
   // the data of the 'store' and 'foo' are taken from somewhere other place from the code, i didnt wrote from where, because im thinking that is it irrelevant to my question
    test[veg] = {"store": store, "foo": foo};
}
```

Comment: im doing this in the loop and it is ONLY adding the LAST element from the loop.... how can i add all elements?

Comment: mock up a fiddle and ill look at whats happening

Comment: this is my full code: http://paste.ofcode.org/SJgH3hg3bUkxshbkaLA8LC the problem is in line 34

Comment: look at updated answer

Comment: the problem was in my code at line 28 because im redeclaring the output[ownerName] = {} everytime in the loop....

Comment: yeah no one would have solved that from your question then

Comment: thank you for your help!