# How to update, push object to object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This question might already been asked but I'm having some trouble understanding it, I'd like to update my javascript object with new objects.

**Object 1 :**

```
var cjson = {};

var t = {
    "infos": "apple",
    "fields": {
        "color":"red",
    }
}

cjson['g320fld1'] = t;
```

**Object 2 :**

```
var data {
  "fruits": {},
  "vegetables": {}
}
```

**Output** : I want to push object 1 to object 2 under **fruits** key. so the ouput look :

```
{
  "fruits": {
    "g320fld1": {
      "infos": "apple",
      "fields": {
      "color":"red",
    }
  },
  "vegetables": {}
}
```

---

What I tried :

**push()**

```
data['fruits'].push(cjson);
```

> Error : ...push() is not a function. (I know push() works on array only so it won't work here.)

**update()**

```
data['fruits'].update(cjson);
```

> Error : ...update() is not a function. (this one gives the same error but since it's another dictionary shouldn't it work as expected ?)

How can I solve this problem ?

---

UPDATE :

Sorry I didn't precise, I don't want to erase older data in fruits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested JSON: How to add (push) new items to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503193/nested-json-how-to-add-push-new-items-to-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

You can use `Object.assign(srcObject,newProperties)` to append new `properties`,`values` to an existing `object`.

```js
var cjson = {};

var t = {
    "infos": "apple",
    "fields": {
        "color":"red"
    }
}

cjson['g320fld1'] = t;

var data ={
  "fruits": {
    otherProperty:"bar"
  },
  "vegetables": {}
}

Object.assign(data.fruits,cjson);

console.log(data)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for !

Answer (score 3):

You can just assign `t` with the key directly to the data object. As long as your keys(`g320fld1` for example) are distinct nothing will be overwritten. I think this makes more sense for what you are trying to do.

```js
var t = {
    "infos": "apple",
    "fields": {
        "color":"red",
    }
}

var data  = {
  "fruits": {},
  "vegetables": {}
}

data.fruits['g320fld1'] = t;

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I thought about that but wouldn't adding another fruit erase the older data inside it ?

Comment: @Lindow yes- but you didn't say that you might have older data, so I didn't take that into account.